# column not present in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark dataframe `df` having IP as `column_name` like below :

```
summary `0.0.0.0` 8.8.8.8  1.0.0.0 1.1.1.1
 count      14      14      14      14
 min        123    231      423     54
 max        2344   241      555     100
```

When I am doing `df.columns` it is giving me a below column list but in list special character of  1st column   **back quote**   is missing.

```
    [0.0.0.0, 8.8.8.8 ,1.0.0.0,1.1.1.1]
```

And when I am performing any operation using this list it gives me an error `column 0.0.0.0 not present in dataframe`.

Also, I tried to change `column_name` by using the below code but is not changing because it is not in the list.

```
  import re
  df = df.select([F.col(col).alias(re.sub("[`]+","",i)) for col in df.columns])
```

How to resolve this issue?

Schema of the df is like below after performing df.printSchema()

```
 root
   |-- summary: string (nullable = true)
   |-- 0.0.0.0: string (nullable = true)
   |-- 8.8.8.8: string (nullable = true)
   |-- 1.0.0.0: string (nullable = true)
   |-- 1.1.1.1: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: spark dataframe is immutable, you need to select that column and put it under different dataframe.

Comment: How do you read/create the inital dataframe `df`? And could you please add the result of `df.printSchema()` ?

Comment: I am reading data from MySQL table and then I am performing pivot operation on that df to derive this data-frame @werner

Comment: the `df.printSchema()` does not show any backticks. No idea then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numbers as the first character of the column name, you always can force adding backticks when query from it

```py
df.select('summary', '`0.0.0.0`').show()
# +-------+-------+
# |summary|0.0.0.0|
# +-------+-------+
# |  count|     14|
# |    min|    123|
# |    max|   2344|
# +-------+-------+

df.select(['summary'] + [f'`{col}`' for col in df.columns if col != 'summary']).show()
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |summary|0.0.0.0|8.8.8.8|1.0.0.0|1.1.1.1|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |  count|     14|     14|     14|     14|
# |    min|    123|    231|    423|     54|
# |    max|   2344|    241|    555|    100|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```